# Secure the pdf produced by Latex

Tags: pdf, copyright, drm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set security options to create PDF using pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31901/how-to-set-security-options-to-create-pdf-using-pdflatex)

I was wondering if there are any provisions for securing the pdf generated by Latex? I mean secure it from copying, or printing (I know that sounds ridiculous but still I was curious) or secure it using a password or all of these? Is that possible?

Comment: It says something about setting password which is not what I want. I was hoping I could secure the pdf from copying. Is that possible?

Comment: To secure, you need a password such that others can not turn off the security settings that you put on the document.

Comment: Short answer: No. However, you can make it less convenient.

Comment: Not for all of the things you mention. For restrictive copying, perhaps [`accsupp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/accsupp). But password and printing (and copying) can be done using [`pdftk`](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/).

Comment: Have a look at the various questions in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drm