# Protecting .pdf file created from latex

Tags: pdf, security, drm

I know it is possible to protect file from printing with Adobe tools, but is this done on latex layer or with pdf tools? And is it also possible to protect created pdf file with password in following situation:
I have latex document, that is intended for customer (as pdf) and I am afraid customer will not pay me for this document. What I want is that the customer will be able to open and review file only first time, and then the pdf locks with password I've preset. Is this possible?

Comment: Letting someone view a PDF only once and then locking it forever sounds quite complicated. In any way this will probably have to dealt with on a non-LaTeX level, see [How to set security options for a PDF using pdflatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31901/35864), [the comments here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52740/35864).

Comment: Why not just send them the first few pages and then await payment before sending the whole thing?

Comment: @IanThompson, good point, I was just thinking of developing something like this idea and I was wondering if something like this already exists.

Comment: @MarkoFrelih, you also have to consider that some of the security features are not available in all PDF readers. I think it *is* possible to do what you want. But not from LaTeX. A librarian showed me a PDF from a German Publisher (I think), it was 100% encrypted and needed a special plugin only available for Adobe Reader (and only on  Windows AFAIR). It even made it so that the PDF could not be printed on a network printer. It had to be on a printer that was locally attached. I agree with Ians suggestion.

Comment: @daleif, do you maybe know which plugin was?

Comment: I think it was these people: http://www.subito-doc.de/, what kind of hackery it is, is unknown.

Comment: I'll note that trying to protect a PDF like this is misguided – there is no real security involved here.  You're going to have to depend your customer to be honest, at which point adding 'security features' is pointless.  Introducing obstructive visual artifacts is, in my experience, usually effective. Of course, the *best* option is just not give them an electronic copy at all.