# Manage document permissions

Tags: pdftex, pdf, drm

Is there a way to manage document permissions by code.

i.e., inside a `.tex` file, insert a command to restrict document only to view and printing?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31901/124577?

Comment: No, this has to be done via external programs. It has to be done after latex is finished with the pdf. As such it is not a job for latex. Note that even if you set the print restrictions in the pdf, it is up to the pdf viewer to decide whether to enforce it.