# It is possible to lock up pdf?

Tags: pdf, copy-paste, drm

I'm searching if it is possible to set permissions in LaTeX code to prevent copy/print/make changes of pdf?
And if it is possible to encrypt pdf in LaTeX code?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Digital signature](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30354/5764)

Comment: This may be heavily dependent on the viewer you use, whether the security applied is adhered to.

Comment: Unless you set a password for opening, such "protection" will be trivial to remove, of course.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Also related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24210/, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31901, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11307/. Please have a look at all of these questions. If one of them answers your question, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: I've seen somwhere here that you can use cmap to destroy te cmapt table on purpose, making it impossible to copy text from the pdf

Comment: @Martin H: It should still be possible to save it as an image and to run OCR over it.

Comment: Nice question. But we read everyday *nothing is 100% secure with the internet*. So always there is a way to break the rule.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.