# How to enable security in LaTeX using pdflatex 1.40.14

Tags: pdf, drm

I want to disable copy/write/edit ... option in my `.pdf` document. I don't want the document to be password protected ...

I am using LaTeX to produce the document.

Here is the shapshot of the document-properties that I would like my document to have ...

[image: snapshot of document properties]

I have tried with adobe acrobat ... but somehow I am not able to achieve the same document security properties ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: In the snapshot I see clearly password protection, and that’s the only reliable way I know to do this … although not with (La)TeX, but with a tool that is executed on the reuslting PDF file.

Comment: For this you can use the [PDF Toolkit](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/). However, it may only be restrictive when using Adobe to view the content. That is, other PDF viewers may not adhere to the restrictions, so this will not be fully secure. See [Generate PDF that is not editable](http://superuser.com/q/488319/100579).

Comment: Related: [Digital signature](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30354/5764)

Comment: There is no reliable method to do this as far as I know. Whether you use a password or not it is trivial to break. It is basically up to the editor to respect your restrictions. Why do you want to make your document inaccessible to users with disabilities anyway?

Comment: Indeed, it is pretty easy to break it accidentally...